# sphinx search issue

Tags: php, sphinx

My sphinx config is as follows

```
source city {
        type            =       mysql
        sql_host        =       localhost
        sql_user        =       root
        sql_pass        =       password
        sql_db          =       database

        sql_query                               = \
                SELECT id,name,cuisine, location,tag  \
                FROM city_search

        sql_query_info                  = SELECT *  FROM city_search WHERE id=$id
}

index city {
        source          =       city
        path            =       /usr/local/sphinx/var/data/city
        charset_type    =       utf-8
        morphology      =       stem_en
        min_stemming_len =      4
        min_word_len    =       3
        min_prefix_len  =       3
        enable_star     =       1
}
```

I have an index for a list of restaurants in a city, for this index I have created a view in Mysql to contain all information that a user can search

restaurant name
cuisine
location etc

Now when i search for a query like "indian" it should ideally return all restaurants containing the word cuisine but

for e.g this record which should be a valid document is not returned This is a column in my view, the cuisine field has all the cuisines that restaurant serves separated by a space

id  name     location  cuisine
311 Verandah Baner     Indian Italian Chinese

not sure what could be the issue

Comment: @Andrej L  in php i run the query as follows                                                              $sphinx->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2);   $sphinx->AddQuery('@(name,cuisine,location,tag) indian',city);

Comment: Try to use $sphinx->query('indian', 'city');

Comment: @Andrej L tried that but still no success!

Comment: Run query from command line: search indian -i city

Comment: Myabe you have problem with your index.

Comment: I ran that from command line too but got the same results, and some documents were missing.

Comment: @AndrejL let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2948/discussion-between-user160108-and-andrej-l)

Comment: When i delete all records and keep only those records which were missed out in search then perform search again the appear in search results is sphinx limiting search results somewhere

Comment: my mistake actually sphinx limits the number of search results to 20 and i was performing a search on only those results.